# Ordenar 2 arrays com diferentes tamanhos em jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, front-end

Estou com o seguinte problema, no meu cenário estou capturando os *Ids* de um *checkbox,* possuo uma lista de objetos JSON onde preciso comparar esses *Ids* com os *Ids* da lista de objetos JSON. O problema é que eles possuem tamanhos diferentes.

**Meu Código**

```
var obj = [
                    { "Id": 1, "Nome": "José" },
                    { "Id": 2, "Nome": "João"},
            { "Id": 3, "Nome": "Maria"}
            ];

var ids = [1, 2];

var j = 0;

var usuarios = [];

for(var i = 0; i < obj.lenght; i++){

  j++;

    if(obj[i].Id == ids[j]){

    usuarios.push(obj[i]);

  }

}

console.log(usuarios);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deveria percorrer a array `ids[]` e verificar se no JSON existe ocorrência em que a chave `Id` possui o valor de cada item da array. Pode usar o método `.filter()` e verificar os dados:

```js
var obj = [
{ "Id": 1, "Nome": "José" },
{ "Id": 2, "Nome": "João"},
{ "Id": 3, "Nome": "Maria"}
];

var ids = [1, 2, 4];

var usuarios = [];

for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){

   obj.filter(function(a){
      if(a.Id == ids[i]){
         usuarios.push(a);
      }
   });

}

console.log(usuarios);
```

Outra forma é fazer o contrário usando `.indexOf()`, sem precisar iterar a array com `for`:

```js
var obj = [
{ "Id": 1, "Nome": "José" },
{ "Id": 2, "Nome": "João"},
{ "Id": 3, "Nome": "Maria"}
];

var ids = [1, 3, 4];

var j = 0;

var usuarios = [];

obj.filter(function(a){
   verifica se o valor da chave Id existe na array
   if(~ids.indexOf(a.Id)){
      usuarios.push(a);
   }
});

console.log(usuarios);
```

Comment: Vlw, ajudou muito.

Comment: Blz... adicionei uma segunda solução que achei até melhor.